# Sharepoint Online 2013 - Analyzing / indexing a WebSite in C#

Tags: search, sharepoint, indexing

I am new to using SP 2013, and I have a question to which I cannot find an answer.
Here is my problem :

I have over a thousand SharePoint web sites.

When I want to change search properties (in order to refine my search) in SP web collection administration panel, I have to manually analyze/index each of my sites.
You'll easily understand that clicking a thousand times on the same button makes me wonder if, by any chance, I couldn't write a bit of code to it for me.

I am currently browsing all the documentation I can find but am not finding anything.
Does anyone have an idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I found an interesting link [here](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/How-to-full-crawl-your-07d24bbd).

The solution is to update the version number of indexing.
SP then triggers the indexation and crawling process for the element of which we just updated the versio number.

For a full crawl/index, we just have to browse all the lists, through all the web sites, updating the version numbers.